# Ubuntu 20.04 best way to make file server?

Tags: server, 20.04, files

I have recently read somewhere that you can simply host a file server with '''python3 -m http.server'''. I plan on using this on a PC running Ubuntu and access using my laptop so I don't have to have all my files on my laptop. Is this the best way to do it? I have seen many others using Apache, Samba and such. I just want to know which would be easiest to just access a few files.

Comment: You can create a *simple* webserver using that command, but that's more along the lines of an example or proof-of-concept. It's insecure, and leaves your whole system wide open to anybody who happens by. It's a bad idea. For "just a few files" a free cloud storage service might be both convenient and secure. Running your own safe, secure file server connected to the dirty internet requires a bit more research on networking and security.

Comment: @user535733 I want the files actually on my PC, not on the cloud. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: What OS will you be using to remotely access the files?

Comment: Also Ubuntu. And possibly windows but not nesscesary

Comment: Are you willing to set up ssh keys for secure access?

Comment: Sure. Even though I have no experience I'll learn

Comment: Next, are you willing to set up DDNS so you can find the server from your remote location?

Answer (score 3):

Install samba `apt install samba samba-common-bin` it is so simple to do too, edit one file, set password, restart daemon and your done. The `nano /etc/samba/smb.conf` in the `[homes]` section change the yes to no like below to have the share read/writable, at the bottom of the file add your share. Then set the password for the `user_name` you want to be able to access the share with `smbpasswd -a user_name` and restart samba `service smbd restart`. All commands run with sudo in front of them in the Terminal application.

```
 # By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
 # next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
read only = no
snip ....
[share-name]
path = /home/user_name/share_directory
writeable=Yes
create mask=0777
directory mask=0777
public=no
```

You do not mention if this is local network only access, I would hope so securing server against the bots that scan the internet 24/7 is next to impossible for a normal user.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `python3 -m http.server` is the most convenient way if you would like to download files remotely. No configurations needed.

Comment: Would there be any way to set a password or something? IDK the documentation confuses me

Comment: @RelmRaydir In my memory not, there is very few configurable options. I use this at home to transfer files temporaily between my devices, but if it comes to long-term file transfer via public network, there should be better solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way.

Walk before you run. Start with exchanging files over ssh.

1. Look up how to set up ssh keys on your client and server for secure, passwordless login.

   - Pro Tip: NEVER trust password logins on the dirty, dirty internet. ALWAYS use keys.
2. Look up how to set up DDNS so you can locate your server from a remote location.
3. Now you are ready to upload and download files using the `scp` command. It's included with ssh, so nothing new to install.
4. Use 'sshfs' with your File Manager. Nautilus handles sshfs automatically -- it's part of the 'connect to server' feature. Windows plug-ins for sshfs are available.
5. Create a backup plan. Internet-connected servers get compromised. Hardware dies. Humans make typos that erase their data. If you data is worth all the effort to serve, then it's worth backing up regularly. Most trustworthy network backups are done over ssh.

Comment: I will tell you if this works later. PC broke down.

Comment: For anybody stumbling upon this question, this is the solution. It should be the top answer.